# Log Analytics questo query to find who created and delete my conatiner and blob

Tags: azure, logging, azure-blob-storage, blob

I have a storage account and i have enabled read write logs in blob level to send blob logs to log analytics but when i am running this query

StorageBlobLogs
where OperationName =~ "CreateContainer" and AccountName =~ 'tester1234567'

I am able to get the logs bt not able to find who created it. Also it would be helpful if i could get query on how to find who created and deleted blob/conatiner.

[image]

Comment: Is it mandatory that you need to use log analytics kusto query to retrieve these details?

Comment: Is there other ways? @SwethaKandikonda

Answer (score 1):

In order to obtain the user that created the container go to the storage and click activity log. Click on the option Export Activity Logs > Add Diagnostic Setting, choose the log categories you want to send to log analytics and select your log analytics workspace.

Go back to the storage account and create a new container (you may have to wait a long time 20 minutes or more for the logs to start collecting before doing this).

Navigate to log analytics and use the query bellow:

```
AzureActivity
| where ResourceProviderValue == "MICROSOFT.STORAGE" and OperationNameValue == "MICROSOFT.STORAGE/STORAGEACCOUNTS/BLOBSERVICES/CONTAINERS/WRITE"
| where parse_json(Properties_d).statusCode == "Created"
| project  parse_json(Properties_d).resource, parse_json(Properties_d).statusCode, parse_json(Properties_d).activityStatusValue, parse_json(Properties_d).httpRequest, parse_json(Properties_d).caller
```

It should show something like this:

[image]

For deletion you can use this query:

```
AzureActivity
| where ResourceProviderValue == "MICROSOFT.STORAGE" and OperationNameValue == "MICROSOFT.STORAGE/STORAGEACCOUNTS/BLOBSERVICES/CONTAINERS/DELETE"
| where parse_json(Properties_d).activityStatusValue == "Success"
| project  parse_json(Properties_d).resource, parse_json(Properties_d).statusCode, parse_json(Properties_d).activityStatusValue, parse_json(Properties_d).httpRequest, parse_json(Properties_d).caller
```

In order to check who deleted a blob the user that is updating/deleting the blob must be using an active directory identity (user or service principal). Using a sas key will not display the username in the logs.

If the authentication used is Active Directory then you should be able to find the objectId of the principal.
Using this query:

```
StorageBlobLogs
| where OperationName == "DeleteBlob" and StatusCode == 202
| project TimeGenerated, AccountName,AuthenticationType,AuthenticationHash,parse_json(parse_json(AuthorizationDetails)[0].principals)[0].id
```

We can see the objectId and the authentication type is Oauth. The first 2 examples are SAS key authentication and we can only see what key is being used.

[image]

Comment: this works thanks. is there a query to find who deleted/created blobs

Comment: @sysadmincrispy please check my updated answer.

Comment: For blob level quering do we need to enable blob level logging like blob read,write and delete or same activity logging is enough?

Comment: i am getting sas key is it able to track with sas key

Comment: StorageBlobLogs
| where OperationName == "CreateBlob" and StatusCode == 201  
| project TimeGenerated, AccountName,AuthenticationType,AuthenticationHash,parse_json(parse_json(AuthorizationDetails)[0].principals)[0].id
is this query right to find who created the blob

Comment: @sysadmincrispy you are getting SAS key because your users or applications are not authenticating via Azure Active Directory and are using a SAS key instead.
You will not be able to get who is using the key. What you can do is assign IAM permission to the users that put things in the storage. The provided query will work for those cases. It will output if you are using sas key and the key name if a key is being used and the username if you are using Azure Active Directory.

Comment: Is the above Create Blob query right?

Comment: I would say so.